# Workday get_worker from USER_ID or email filter

Tags: workday-api

I am trying to find an API to get worker on email basis. Can someone please help me in the same.

Answer (score 2):

No, there is no such way to get worker by email.
You may refer to the api for get workers here -> https://community.workday.com/sites/default/files/file-hosting/productionapi/Human_Resources/v30.1/Get_Workers.html

but you sure can retrieve data using employee_id, using the request xml as follows:-

```
<wd:Get_Workers_Request xmlns:wd="urn:com.workday/bsvc" version="30.0">
    <wd:Request_References bsvc:Skip_Non_Existing_Instances="false">
        <wd:Worker_Reference >
            <wd:ID wd:type="Enter ID type here...for eg WID,Employee_ID">Enter WID or other ID type you have choosen</wd:ID>
        </wd:Worker_Reference>
    </wd:Request_References>
  </wd:Get_Workers_Request>
```

Answer (score 1):

No, this isn't possible through the Public APIs.

Your Workday team or Integration Administrator could set up a custom report enabled for REST calls with email address as the prompt, though. The Workers from Prompt data source is good for this.