# Is there a way to query Workday API for PTO Requests?

Tags: c#, soap, workday-api

I'm working on a project to display pending PTO Requests. Searching around on SO showed that I can set up a custom report to expose user records and be queryable by something like an email. Link: [Workday get_worker from USER_ID or email filter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53440759/workday-get-worker-from-user-id-or-email-filter)

My problem now is that it doesn't seem like it's possible to just get a PTO Request. There are endpoints to Enter and Adjust but not to Find or Fetch. Leave of Absence is directly tied to the Worker entity but PTO is just... something else.

I've tried querying every endpoint that seemed worthwhile. Timeblock, Timesheets, Get_Event_Details, Absence_Input, and probably a few more I've forgotten about.

Judging from the UI (I do not have access to the front-end of Workday, I'm going off of some PDFs I found from universities who use Workday), Time Off Requests are their own separate module but there doesn't seem to be any model association to be made. :(

Comment: Try query for Time_Off_Service_Date : See https://community.workday.com/sites/default/files/file-hosting/productionapi/Human_Resources/v20/Get_Workers.html

Comment: There are 2 problems: 1) I don't have access to the HR API, unfortunately, and 2) That would just return a datetime object, whereas I need the actual PTO object to process it as accepted or denied.

Comment: The link you  provided IS  WorkDay.COM.  I just provided the documentation for the library.

Comment: The only link I provided was to another SO question. The documentation linked doesn't solve my problem as A) As I said, I do not have access to HR and B) A datetime object doesn't give me a PTO Entity to accept or deny through the API.

Comment: You have workday but don't have all the modules loaded?